# Save google authenticated user into mysql database with node.js and passport.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, passport.js, google-oauth

I build a simple web application where the user has notes. I want the user to be able to sign in with a google account as well, but the user didn't save into the database. The local login works but the social login doesn't. Wherever I searched I only found a solution in which mongodb was used. What is the correct way with mysql?
Here is my passport.js file:

```
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser((req, user, done) => {

    conn.query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = ? OR facebook_id = ? OR google_id", [user.id, 
      user.facebook_id, user.google_id], (err, rows) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return done(null, err);
        }
            done(null, user);
    });
});

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
        clientID: configAuth.googleAuth.clientID,
        clientSecret: configAuth.googleAuth.clientSecret,
        callbackURL: configAuth.googleAuth.callbackURL,
        passReqToCallback: true,
        profileFields: configAuth.googleAuth.profileFields
    },
        function (req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {

            process.nextTick(function () {
                conn.query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE google_id = ?", [profile.id], (err, user) => {
                    if (err) {
                        return done(err);
                    } else if (user) {
                        return done(null, user);
                    } else {
                        let newUser = {
                            google_id: profile.id,
                            google_token: accessToken,
                            google_email: profile.emails[0].value,
                            google_name: profle.name.givenName + ' ' + profile.name.familyName
                        };

                        conn.query("INSERT INTO user (google_id, google_token, google_email, google_name) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)",
                            [newUser.google_id, newUser.google_token, newUser.google_email, newUser.google_name], (err, rows) => {
                                if (err) {
                                    console.log(err);
                                }

                                return done(null, newUser);
                            })
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    ));
```

And here are the routes:

```
app.get('/auth/google', passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile', 'email'] }));

app.get('/auth/google/callback', passport.authenticate('google', {
    successRedirect: '/main',
    failureRedirect: '/'
}));
```

I can log in, I didn't receive an error message, but if I want to assign a new note to the user it doesn't add it because it doesn't save the user to the database.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget to put `?` after the google_id.
Example:

```
google_id=?
```